# 店番 vs. 店員 - are these synonymous?

Tags: word-usage

Does 店番{みせばん} have the same meaning as 店員{てんいん}? Can these words be used interchangeably?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

店員 is a primary term for clerks of stores of any size. Workers at convenience stores and supermarkets are typical 店員.

店番 is someone who looks after a small shop alone while the owner is away. 番 is a kanji that means *watch*, *keeper* or *lookout*. 店番 usually sell items like regular clerks, but they don't  necessarily do so. Even a child or [a dog](http://bungalowmag.jp/14301) can be a 店番 (of course this is not common). At least in modern Japanese, 店番 doesn't refer to store clerks in general.